# How to find out how many decimals a number has?

Tags: java, loops

How can I verify how many decimals a number has in Java?

I need to calculate PI to a certain number of decimal, and I want to know how I can stop my loop when I reach the desired decimals number?

Comment: You can format the PI output for required decimals

Comment: You probably use `BigDecimal` for the calculation, which has a `scale()` method to return the number of decimals of the number. So, for 3.1415 `scale()` would yield 4. Perhaps you can use it in your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can't check the number of decimals on a `double` directly, but you can convert it to a `String` using `String str = number + "";` and then check `str.length`.

Comment: It's probably not going to help solve the actual problem, but totally the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use BigDecimal for your calculation you could set the scale to the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a small precision e.g. 15 decimal places, you can use double for that. To specify the number of digits you could use Math.pow(10, -decimalPlaces) to calculate the smallest allowed deviation.

Answer (score 0):

1) you firstly convert it to string

2)Then take a  substring from '.' to end

3) Thenget the length of this substring